# Trying to request user permissions for push notifications in different view fails

Tags: swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to request user for push notifications permission after successful login.

This is the code in my delegate file

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate  {
 func registerPushNotifications() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, _ in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how i'm trying to declare it in a view.

```
.onAppear {
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!.registerPushNotifications()
}
```

The error I keep getting is **Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.AppDelegate' (0x1e18f9688) to '[AppName].AppDelegate' (0x1040300a0).**

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: Do you set the app delegate anywhere?

Comment: yea I did when I was defining the entry point for the app -
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate